# MacBook Air microphone volume extremely low

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone, sound-volume

Everytime I try to make call with Skype or Google Hangouts from my MacBook Air, the embedded internal microphone volume is too low. I am sure it is working, because when I shout loudly enough, the people on the other side of call can hear me, but only really quietly.

I have Macbook Air 13'' late 2010, right now running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, but I had this problem since the very beginning.

I have played with volume and also input volume levels in Settings → Sound, volume is on maximum level, but still unusable. I have Googled for the problem and tried several workarounds, none seems to be addressing my issue/working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After closely looking on microphone input on the left side of my MacBook Air, I have found that the little holes are blocked with dust or something like that.

So **I took the needle and removed the dust from microphone holes**, and it's now working well!

*Note: I know this would seem like obvious solution, but the holes are so little you cannot see anything in them unless you look really closely (or, more probably, use magnifier).*

Comment: A good thing to use to clean out the microphone hole is compressed air. You can find it in a lot of stores, even most Wal-Marts.